# Sitemap is redirecting to non secure site

Tags: sitemap

### We have a multilang site and used a sitemap for each lang. Then we used a sitemapindex where we have a mapping of sitemaps avaliable :

```
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap_en.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2018-07-10</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap_fr.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2018-07-10</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap_nl.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2018-07-10</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

---

The sitemap is working ok and valids. However when I pass the console of google and launch the reading of sitemap for indexing, I have a 301 redirect from https to http. That is not happening when I type the url of my site , and i have a rule in my htaccess for avoid this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Somebody have some idea why when google tries to index the site it gets a redirection from https to http ?